# read csv and Iterate through 10 row blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to read a CSV file and Iterate through 10-row blocks.
The data is quite unusual, with two columns and 10-row blocks.

57485 rows x 2 columns in the format below:

```
Grid-ref=   1,148
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630
 3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 1770 2580 2630

Grid-ref=   1,311
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450
  490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460  420  530  450

Grid-ref=   1,312
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
  460  280  260  220  190  240  430  520  450  400  520  410
```

Every 10 rows consist of a grid reference and two records X/Y ref.
The grid reference and X value is in column 1, the Y value is in column 2, and then 9 rows with 12 columns, in column one.

```
The blocks (x) 0 - 9, represent months (Jan - December
The blocks (y) 0 - 9, represent years (1991-2000)

So for 0, is 1991 
3020 is January 1991, 2820 is February 1991

Grid-ref = 1 (X),148 (Y)
```

The code below reads 10 rows, but keeps repeating the first row in all following 10-row blocks??

I don't understand why it keeps repeating the first row??
Any suggestions to resolve this would be appreciated..

```
## Python 3.6

## Read in the datasets (they are in CSV format) 
data = pd.read_csv('cru-ts-2-10-1991-2000-cutdown.csv', skiprows=5, na_values =  [-999] )

## View data    >> 57485 rows x 2 columns
#print(data)
#print(len(data))   ## len = 57485

## header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Grid-ref', 'Xref', 'Yref'], ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ] ])

# df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 11), 
# index=['1991','1992','1993','1994','1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001'], 
#  columns=header)

# print(data.head(10)) ## prints chunks of 10 rows

def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

for group in chunker(data, 10):
    print(group)
```

The first two block:

```
                                      Grid-ref=   1   148
0   3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 ...   NaN
1   3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 ...   NaN
2   3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 ...   NaN
3   3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 ...   NaN
4   3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 ...   NaN
5   3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 ...   NaN
6   3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 ...   NaN
7   3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 ...   NaN
8   3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 ...   NaN
9   3020 2820 3040 2880 1740 1360  980  990 1410 ...   NaN
                                        Grid-ref=   1    148
10                                      Grid-ref=   1  311.0
11    490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460 ...    NaN
12    490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460 ...    NaN
13    490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460 ...    NaN
14    490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460 ...    NaN
15    490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460 ...    NaN
16    490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460 ...    NaN
17    490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460 ...    NaN
18    490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460 ...    NaN
19    490  290  280  230  200  250  440  530  460 ...    NaN
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your CSV.

Comment: What do you want the table to look like? Should grid ref be integrated as a column? pandas is good for uniform columnar data and this dataset isn't quite that. You may want to preprocess with the regular python csv module to get the data you want either as  a list ofr lists to be handed to pandas or as an intermediate file that has been converted to the form you want.

Comment: I have added the first few blocks of data above, I cannot add it to the comments.

Comment: Greetings, I want to extract the Grid-ref, X/Y, and then create a DataFrame with the Grid-ref, X/Y, date with reading.                                                                  For 0 = Jan-1991 = 3020, Feb-1991 = 2820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is good for uniform columnar data. If your input isn't uniform, you can preprocess it and then load the dataframe. This one is easy, all you need to do is scan for grid headers and remove them. Since the data itself is numeric, separated by whitespace, a simple split will parse it. This example creates a list but if the dataset is large, it may be reasonable to write to an intermediate file instead.

```
import csv
import re
import pandas as  pd

grid_re = re.compile(r"Grid-ref=\s*(\d+),(\d+)")

with open('test.csv') as fobj:
    table = []
    try:
        while True:
            # find next block
            for line in fobj:
                match = grid_re.search(line)
                if match:
                    grid_xy = list(match.groups())
                    break
            else:
                raise StopIteration()
            for _ in range(10):
                line = next(fobj)
                # add row plus grid columns
                table.append(line.strip().split() + grid_xy)
    except StopIteration:
        pass

df = pd.DataFrame(table)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Using the wrong library, like putting petrol into a diesel.

Comment: I ran the code, but get an empty DataFrame.                                                                 
for line in fobj:   This prints the blocks, with an additional line.                                                match = grid_re.search(line)   This returns None, from Column 2